'overscroll-behavior: none' doesn't prevent scrolling behind modal
I have a page in which content in the main body an be clicked to trigger the appearance of a modal displaying more info about the content. This modal div is sized to the window. In some cases the modal content will scroll, in some cases it won't. In any case, while the modal is open, I don't want the body to be scrolled at any point.
I have tried using the property overscroll-behavior, however, despite the use case seeming pretty straightforward, I can't seem to get it to work. The body continues to scroll despite the modal being open. Is there something simple I'm missing?
I've also tried adding overflow: hidden; to the body (even though it shouldn't be necessary for overscroll-behavior to work), though that has no effect either.
The solution should "freeze" the scroll position of the body — once the modal disappears the body should not have changed it's scroll position.


p {
  font-size: 84px;
}

.modal {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  color: white;
  border: 5px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overscroll-behavior: none;
}
<html>
  <body>
    <p>I am a body full of content, enough to make it scroll.</p>
    <p>I am a body full of content, enough to make it scroll.</p>
    <p>I am a body full of content, enough to make it scroll.</p>
    <p>I am a body full of content, enough to make it scroll.</p>
    <div class="modal">
      I am in the modal, I don't scroll.
    </div>
  </body>
</html>




You can achieve the desired output by using some JavaScript to add a class to the modal element dynamically.
Look at this example:


function openModal() {
  var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
  modal.classList.add("active");
  document.body.classList.add("modal-open");
}

function closeModal() {
  var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
  modal.classList.remove("active");
  document.body.classList.remove("modal-open");
}
body.modal-open {
  overflow: hidden;
}

p {
  font-size: 84px;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: white;
  border: 5px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.modal.active {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
<button onclick="openModal()">Open Modal</button>

<p>I am a body full of content, enough to make it scroll.</p>
<p>I am a body full of content, enough to make it scroll.</p>
<p>I am a body full of content, enough to make it scroll.</p>
<p>I am a body full of content, enough to make it scroll.</p>
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  I am in the modal, I don't scroll.
</div>




Sorry, the issue is not making the modal open and close — I didn't include it in the minimum viable code because it's not part of the issue I'm experiencing. The issue is that the body scrolls despite the modal covering the visible entirety of the body.
